# Fargate is serverless container means that I can have 0 container working if there is no traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am building an app that has no traffic, or very small traffic, and I am using Golang Docker with several micro services.

I also use AWS / EC2, but I am considering AWS Fargate to run my container.

If I have no traffic, should I pay for a running container or should I pay only when there is traffic ?

Comment: nope, fargate is not serverless. Your containers still run on ec2 (24/7 switched on, as a server), just that you can't see the instance, nor maintain it. (maintainless could be appropiated?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fargate just means that you do not have to manage the underlying Container Host. The containers themselves are still managed by ECS.

For a more serverless approach, the Lambda service would be more applicable for most use cases.

Fargate can be used in conjunction with Lambda to run tasks that are too long running to be appropriate for Lambda.

Comment: Ok. But something is not clear for me, in Fargate pricing page: https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/pricing/, in the example, it takes a task that is executed everyday 10 minutes. Should I understand fargate use case it for cron jobs ? So it is not an api, it is a cron job or something like that. For an API, should we stick to API Gateway + Lambda ?

Comment: Yes, the most commonly cited use cases are for batch processing jobs. 

It could also be useful for upfront testing an application that is intended to be ECS hosted in production without having to stand up the host platform.

I have also used it to run Jenkins slaves which will typically only run builds for a matter of minutes.